# NA value in mean?

Tags: r, mean, na, na.rm

```
Whenever I use
df %>% remove_empty(c("rows", "cols")) and then take mean of df using 
 df %>%
    summarise(mean= mean(value),
            sd= sd(value),
            n = length(value)) 
I get mean= NA sd=NA  n= 2000
```

However, when I use this code:
print(mean(df$value, na.rm= TRUE))   mean= 1.23(..)

Why is this happening?

Like above, I'm not sure why this is occuring.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove_empty` only removes rows or columns which are *entirely* made of `NA` values.  Rows/columns which only have *some* `NA` values are not removed.